# WHERE before GROUP BY and HAVING after GROUP BY in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Which out of WHERE before GROUP BY and HAVING after GROUP BY is a better choice according to time complexity?

Comment: What makes you think it has *any* effect on time complexity?

Comment: WHERE and HAVING serve two very different purposes. It's not a question which one is more efficient, it's a question which one is the correct thing to use.

Comment: In WHERE before GROUP BY,
First the rows are filtered and then the grouping happens.

Whereas in the other case,
First the grouping takes place and then the rows are filtered.

Just wanted to know which one is faster or which one comes under 'good practices'

Comment: Again: both approaches have a different result. You can't compare them.

Comment: OK! Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: I disagree with some of the others. Yes, they certainly have different purposes, but if you can filter your data set down with a "WHERE" before using a "HAVING" then do so. This will result in less records needing to be aggregated by the group by.

Comment: @DonkeyKongII Why so? WHERE clause filter row first which mean it will go through all the row which require certain time.

Comment: @DonkeyKongII I'm not sure that's a legitimate choice. If you don't put the filter in WHERE, then your GROUP BY will not behave correctly as it will be operating on the wrong set of rows. The reality is that WHERE filters rows from FROM/JOIN and HAVING filters rows that result from GROUP BY. You put things in each clause based on the need, not performance considerations. I can't really think of exceptions that make any sense.

Comment: @stride I'm not saying it's the right way to think about it, but certainly you can yield the same results for a query with conditions in the where, and a query with conditions in the having. I believe the OP is talking about situations exactly like that, where your condition could plausibly go in the "having" or the "where" in which case it's always better to put it in the where. See my db-fiddle for an example https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/33x4upVEcgTMNehiHCKzfN/0

Comment: @DonkeyKongII In the second query, there's no point to having a group by in the first place. Yes, you can do it, but it would be a poorly designed query aside from any performance concerns.

Comment: That was a simple example; there are certainly other more complex examples where results would be the same. And I wouldn't say there is no point to the group by, you may have a reason for returning one row with all the names concatenated vs. two rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, lets clarify what each does.

`WHERE` - this is what you are filtering data based on.  The columns here are a bit part of your query performance time.  If you are looking for a specific type of thing, or date ranges, a customer or whatever.  You would want an index on the primary table you are querying against to help match these columns.  That will be where your performance is going to get the most help.

`GROUP BY` - this is sometimes used in conjunction with a where.  Such as querying all customers who have place orders and grouping based on a city, state, region, time period.  So the WHERE clause would be the primary for getting the data, but if your index ALSO has columns associated with the group by, that TOO can improve performance.

Now, the primary purpose of the GROUP BY is to perform some sort of aggregation of data based on a common thing, such as previously stated.  You may want a query of all transactions purchased by customers within a given time period.  So, you may have a WHERE clause that indicates the from/to date period.  But, now the grouping, you want per customer, so you may want a

```
   CustomerID,
   SUM(CustomerPurchaseAmount) totalPurchases, 
   count(*) as TimesOrdered
```

so the group by CustomerID would do the aggregates per the sample above and have a result of one record per customer in this example.

The `HAVING` clause is AFTER the where of what records to query, the GROUP BY which performs the aggregations and can act on some aggregate.  Such as I only want customers purchasing from X to Y dates and their total purchases is greater than some amount.  So the having clause might be something like

```
HAVING SUM(CustomerPurchaseAmount) > 500
```

So, from the example, date applied via where, the group gets the totals per specific customer, and now the HAVING is applied to see what customers had ex: more than 500 in purchases.

Performance is significantly handled by having good indexes to match your more common queries on the WHERE clause, but can also be optimized to ALSO support needs of GROUP BY as a secondary consideration.  Having just comes along after all else is done.